# accessing and sorting array objects in json using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I’m playing around with json objects in javascript and wanted see if someone could help me out with a problem

My json file contains a list of hash objects containing a key (id) and the value being an array of [ ipaddress, timestamp, url]

e.g.

```
{"output":
    {
    "1":["10.0.0.1","2012-07-11T11:41:42+01:00","http://myurl.com"],
    "2":["10.0.0.1","2012-07-11T11:45:42+01:00","http://myurl2.com"],
    "3":["192.168.1.1","2012-07-11T11:41:47+01:00","http://myurl3.com"]
    }
}
```

What I want to do is be able to sort on the contents of the arrays

For example I’d like to go through the json and pull out the highest timestamp for each ip address

So an example output for the json above would look like:-

```
10.0.0.1 - http://myurl2.com
192.168.1.1 - http://myurl3.com
```

At the moment I have a simple function to output the raw data in a div, but I’m sure I could handle the arrays better

```
  var displayOutput = function(data){
    var container = $("#fragment-1");
   var body = “”;
    $.each(data.output, function(key, val) {
      var arr = val.toString().split(",");
      body = body + arr[0]+ ' - ' +  arr[1]) + ' - ' +  arr[2]
    });
    container.html(body);                                                
  };
```

Comment: You have to convert your data into another structure which is sortable. For example an object with IPs as properties, each value being an array of timestamps (which then can be sorted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change the format as JSON arent to easy to sort.

Maybe a multi dimensional array?

Maybe this might help: [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/how-to-sort-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Or this: http://www.devcurry.com/2010/05/sorting-json-array.html

Or this: [Sorting a JSON object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222690/sorting-a-json-object-in-javascript)

One of these will definitely lead to to a good solution. Need any help ask :)

Comment: Your answer is a bit confusing. It does not make sense to talk about "sorting JSON is not easy" because JSON is a data format, just like XML.

Comment: I wouldnt recommend it, al though i provided links which explain how to do it with examples

Comment: thanks all, in the end I converted the json to a multidimensional array and went from there

Answer (score 0):

You can Use underscore.js library. For example, you can sort collection with:

```
_.sortBy(yourData.output, function (elem) {
    return new Date(elem[1]).getTime() - new Date().getTime();
});
```

Of course you need to parse JSON to JavaScript object first.

Comment: Object properties are always unordered, I doubt underscore.js can sort them.

Comment: Sure, my example has a mistake, but _ provides good tools to manipulate with JavaScript collections.