# Sort basic json object

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I have a very simple json object,

```
{
   "costA": 9617,
   "costB": 11100,
   "costC": 13208,
   "costD": 9910
}
```

Is it possible to sort this json (in javascript) to get the resultant?

```
{
   "costA": 13208,
   "costB": 11100,
   "costC": 9910,
   "costD": 9617
}
```

Note: `key` names can change..

Comment: you want to sort by key or by value?

Comment: take a look at this probably what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222690/sorting-a-json-object-in-javascript

Comment: looks like he wants to sort the value and reinsert into the keys

Comment: Take a look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/jquery-sorting-json-by-properties

Comment: Its a key value pair. The way you are sorting seems wrong. You should use array instead.

Comment: @subirkumarsao can you post an answer using an array? I need to map the largest value back to the label, that's where I was getting stuck..

Comment: @JanHančič tried a lot of stuff .. head's just stopped working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below JavaScript gives the result you're after: `{costA: 13208, costB: 11100, costC: 9910, costD: 9617}`:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"costA": 9617, "costB": 11100, "costC": 13208, "costD": 9910}');
var values = [], keys = [], key, i;
for (key in obj) {
    keys.push(key);
    values.push(obj[key]);
}
values.sort(function (a, b) { return b-a; });
keys.sort();
for (i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
    key = keys[i];
    val = values[i];
    obj[key] = val;
}

console.log(obj);
```

See also [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HrDgw/1/).