# Sort JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I have JSON object of the form

```
[
    {
        "Var1": "text1",
        "var2": "text2",
        "var3": "text3",
        "Saving": "integer1"
    },
    {
        "Var1": "text11",
        "var2": "text22",
        "var3": "text33",
        "Saving": "integer2"
    },
    {
        "Var1": "text111",
        "var2": "text222",
        "var3": "text333",
        "Saving": "text"
    }
]
```

"Saving" variable of the JSON contains both text and integer. I want to sort the JSON such that Saving with maximum integer value is top followed text.
I am using javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting a JSON object in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222690/sorting-a-json-object-in-javascript)

Comment: You want to sort by "Saving" property?

Comment: @PhilippeBoissonneault No it is not.

Comment: I voted to reopen it because the answer in this question is much simpler than the one in possible duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[
    {
        "Var1": "text1",
        "var2": "text2",
        "var3": "text3",
        "Saving": "a7"
    },
    {
        "Var1": "text11",
        "var2": "text22",
        "var3": "text33",
        "Saving": 2
    },
    {
        "Var1": "text111",
        "var2": "text222",
        "var3": "text333",
        "Saving": "n3"
    }
].sort(function(a,b){
    var aNum = parseInt(a.Saving, 10);
    var bNum = parseInt(b.Saving, 10);
    if(isNaN(aNum) && isNaN(bNum)){
        return a.Saving > b.Saving;
    }
    if(isNaN(aNum)){
     return true;
    }
    if(isNaN(bNum)){
        return false;
    }
    return aNum > bNum;
});
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/OluC/1/watch?js,console,output)

Comment: You should probably specify the base 10 for `parseInt` as it's octal by default in some browsers.

Comment: Indeed... edit made.  Thank you @RayCheng

Answer (score 2):

You can use lodash's `sortBy` method:  http://lodash.com/docs#sortBy

> _.sortBy([1, 2, 3], function(num) { return Math.sin(num); });
>   // → [3, 1, 2]
>
> _.sortBy([1, 2, 3], function(num) { return this.sin(num); }, Math);
>   // → [3, 1, 2]
>
> // using "_.pluck" callback shorthand
>   _.sortBy(['banana', 'strawberry', 'apple'], 'length');
>   // → ['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry']

If you aren't able to include lodash, please see their source here for how to implement: https://github.com/bestiejs/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js

```
function sortBy(collection, callback, thisArg) {
  var index = -1,
      length = collection ? collection.length : 0,
      result = Array(typeof length == 'number' ? length : 0);

  callback = lodash.createCallback(callback, thisArg, 3);
  forEach(collection, function(value, key, collection) {
    var object = result[++index] = getObject();
    object.criteria = callback(value, key, collection);
    object.index = index;
    object.value = value;
  });

  length = result.length;
  result.sort(compareAscending);
  while (length--) {
    var object = result[length];
    result[length] = object.value;
    releaseObject(object);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Elements of Array can be sorted by Array.Sort method. You can pass a custom function into the method to sort it by any properties of its elements.

Comment: but the property is a mix of integer and text

Comment: @user2129794, treat all of them as  text.

Comment: @RayCheng Can you write a bried code to help me better??

Comment: Go with @Bluetoft solution.