# Sorting array of objects with comma-delimited price strings in numeric order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, decimal

I'm using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222690/sorting-a-json-object-in-javascript) to sort an array of objects. This is the function:

```
function sortJsonArrayByProperty(objArray, prop, direction){
    if (arguments.length<2) throw new Error("sortJsonArrayByProp requires 2 arguments");
    var direct = arguments.length>2 ? arguments[2] : 1; //Default to ascending
    if (objArray && objArray.constructor===Array){
        var propPath = (prop.constructor===Array) ? prop : prop.split(".");
        objArray.sort(function(a,b){
            for (var p in propPath){
                if (a[propPath[p]] && b[propPath[p]]){
                    a = a[propPath[p]];
                    b = b[propPath[p]];
                }
            }
            // convert numeric strings to integers
            a = a.match(/^\d+$/) ? +a : a;
            b = b.match(/^\d+$/) ? +b : b;
            return ( (a < b) ? -1*direct : ((a > b) ? 1*direct : 0) );
        });
    }
}
```

It's a great solution.

But I have a problem with a column that store **prices** in this format:

```
950,75
1234,99
500,00
```

So, I have values with a **comma** separating decimals.
Then, instead of this sequence:

```
222,55
550,00
2000,99
3000,00
```

I'm getting:

```
2000,99
222,55
3000,00
550,00
```

I'm trying to do some modification at this part:

```
a = a.match(/^\d+$/) ? +a : a; 
b = b.match(/^\d+$/) ? +b : b;
```

But that isn't working. What's wrong?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON object". JSON is a limited string serialization of JavaScript objects.

Comment: What you're sorting isn't a JSON object. It's a JavaScript array, containing JavaScript objects. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. If you're writing code, and you're not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Why don't replacing commas `,`  with decimal dots `.` and do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, the decimal separator is always `.`, never `,` as it is in some locales. So to convert numeric strings that use `,` as a decimal to JavaScript numbers, you do this:

```
theNumber = +theString.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,/g, '.');
```

or

```
theNumber = parseFloat(theString.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,/g, '.'));
```

...depending on whether you want to ignore trailing invalid characters (`+` doesn't, `parseFloat` does).

So that would suggest:

```
aVal = +a.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,/g, '.');
bVal = +b.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,/g, '.');
if (!isNaN(aVal) && !isNaN(bVal)) {
    a = aVal;
    b = bVal;
}
```

Comment: Inside "if" I've changed !isNaN(a) by !isNaN(aVal) and it worked perfectly.
I got your logic here.
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @GustavoTarchiani: Doh! Editing error, now fixed. Glad that helped.

Comment: Don't worry! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The comma is not recognized by JavaScript as part of a valid litteral number, so you cannot use unary + or any other built-in method to convert to a number. You need to replace commas with a period and then coerce to Number.

```
a = a.match(/^(\d+),(\d+)$/) ? +(a[1]+'.'+a[2]) : a;
```