# How do we sort Nested Dictionaries where entries are sorted by keys(within each nested dictionary)?

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

A nested dictionary is a dictionary whose keys are strings and whose values are string or other nested dictionaries. Given a string representation , we need to return a String representation where the entries are sorted by key(within each nested dictionary)

```
Input: { b:{cb:cranberry,bb:blueberry},a:apple,c:cherry}
Output:  { a:apple,b:{bb:blueberry,cb:cranberry},c:cherry}
```

Here entries in outermost dictionary have been reordered by key (i.e from `b,a,c` to `a,b,c`) . Similarly , the entries in innermost dictionary have been reordered by key(i.e from `cb,bb` to `bb,cb`)

Also, Note : Output will have same general format as input string. except that within each nested dictionary, keys should be sorted in increasing lexicographic order ( eg. `a<b<bb<bbb<bc<c`)

Comment: Here's how to do it in JavaScript, if that's any help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222690/sorting-a-json-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

This smells like an interview question. Anyway.

Basic Ideas:

- You iterate the input char by char.
- Use a `Stack` to store each dict depth by depth. The top of the stack will have the deepest sub-dict
- Every time a sub-dict is scanned, convert the sub-dict to a String value and assign the value belonging to the key from the parent.
- You can represent each dict / sub-dict with `TreeMap` in Java.
  Using `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap` because `TreeMap` sort the entries by their keys already.

It's hard to make it "clear" without giving out the complete solution. Hope it helps.